# Unable to get wordpress register_nav_menus working

Tags: wordpress, menu, themes

I am building my 1st theme, and got stucked with showing menu option on admin's screen under appearance. I refered various support thread but none of the solution is working for me.

Codes in function.php

```
<?php
//Create Nav menu
if (function_exists(register_nav_menus)) {
register_nav_menus( array('primary' => 'Header Navigation') );
 }
 ?>
```

Codes in header.php

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-nav' , 'container'=>'nav') );
?>
```

I am executing this on localserver and wordpress version 4.0

image of header.php

https://i.stack.imgur.com/adv7Z.png

image of function.php

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFIkj.png

Thats all of it.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rename **function.php** to **functions.php** , note the the "s". http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained

Second try registering the menu inside a hook  like `init` or `after_theme_setup`

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );

function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Header Navigation' );
}
```

Comment: renaming function.php to functions.php have sorted this out.. thanks for sorting this out

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some arguments (and a comma in your array). You need to pass in a `menu` name:

```
$args = array(
    'menu'            => 'primary',
    'container'       => 'nav',
    'container_class' => 'main-nav',
);

wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

Also be aware that this menu must exist in the admin, and **must be assigned** to the menu location you just created.

Comment: hi, i have corrected my mistake and  added the missing arguments, but still the menu option is not showing up.

Comment: @SaurabhChaudhary You also needs to go to the WP admin and create the actual menu that is to be displayed at that location; Lord knows that's tripped me a number of times!

Comment: The problem is wordpress backend admin's panel is not showing menu option even after registering menu correctly. I am trying this since morning..